# Reversed breadcrumb issue

Tags: php, mysql

My navigation table looks like this. [image]

It based on a parent<->child scheme.

I'm using following code to generate breadcrumb.

```
function makeBreadcrumb($current, $lang, $db){
      $q = $db->query("SELECT id, parent, $lang AS name FROM nav WHERE id = '$current'");
      $row=$q->fetch_object();
      echo "<li>";
            echo '<a href="?id=' . $row->id . '">' . $row->name . '</a>';
            echo "</li>\n\n";
     if($row->parent) makeBreadcrumb($row->parent, $lang, $db);
    }
```

But getting reversed breadcrumb: it shows `child>parent` instead of `parent>child`
.How to fix that?

Comment: What determines which pages are parents and which are children - the `menu` column?

Comment: don't u see `parent` column? it's highlighted in screenshot

Comment: Oh, just noticed that - looks like you're calling your recursive function too late is the problem, like ArtoAle said in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very easy...you can simply put the recursive call ***before*** the `echo` statment, like this:

```
function makeBreadcrumb($current, $lang, $db){
      $q = $db->query("SELECT id, parent, $lang AS name FROM nav WHERE id = '$current'");
      $row=$q->fetch_object();
     if($row->parent) makeBreadcrumb($row->parent, $lang, $db);
      echo "<li>";
            echo '<a href="?id=' . $row->id . '">' . $row->name . '</a>';
            echo "</li>\n\n";

    }
```

But I raccomend you not to do a query for each node in the tree. It could be very resource-expenshive.

Comment: +1 Except that making a query for each node is usually the *least* expensive way to do it. Say you have 10K records in that table, you're not going to fetch all records to build a breadcrumb of 3 nodes. A great solution in this case is using **prepared statements** however.

Comment: "Say you have 10K records in that table, you're not going to fetch all records to build a breadcrumb of 3 nodes." Don't you see `WHERE id = '$current'` ???

Comment: @L0rd DEVdem0rt: That's beside the point. Point is, it's the least expensive way to do it and you don't have a choice. You'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: @netcoder, your're right, but if you define substets of element (e.g, you have lot of root node, and small tree) you can give it an id, query all the row with that id and query the db only once.ù